# Ensure all methods in a chained comparator in javascript are run before evaulating?

Tags: javascript

If I have the following snippet:

```
onClose={() => !isPostingConfig && onClickAway() && clearRoleErrors()}
```

I understand that if `!isPostingConfig` returns a `falsy` value, both `onClickAway()` and `clearRoleError()` will not be evaluated i.e. the methods will not run.

I know I can circumvent this by wrapping a method around this.

```
evaulate(){
  var a = !isPostingConfig
  var b = onClickAway()
  var c = clearRoleError()

  return a && b && c
}
```

But is there an easier to ensure all methods in a chained operator are run before evaluating the operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is there an easier to ensure all methods in a chained operator are run before evaluating the operators?

You can use `&` instead of `&&` assuming you're dealing with booleans (you are with `!isPostingConfig`, but I don't know the return values of your functions). `&` is the bitwise AND operator. It always evaluates both of its operands. Then it converts them to 32-bit integers and ANDs them together. `false` converts to `0` and `true` converts to `1`, so with boolean values, `a & b & c` will be `1` if they're **all** `1` or `0` if any of them is `0`.

Of course, the result will be a number, not a boolean, but you can convert it back:

```
onClose={() => Boolean(!isPostingConfig & onClickAway() & clearRoleErrors())}
```

You might give yourself `andAll` and `orAll` helper functions:

```
onClose={() => andAll(!isPostingConfig, onClickAway(), clearRoleErrors())}
```

The array methods `every` (= AND) and `some` (= OR) would work, but it's a bit cumbersome:

```
onClose={() => [!isPostingConfig, onClickAway(), clearRoleErrors()].every(Boolean)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an array of functions, and loop with `Array.reduce()`. Combine the result of each function with the previous one using the logical and operator (`&&`). All the functions will execute, and the end result stay `true` if all return `true`, or `false` if at least one returns `false`.

```
const evaluate = (...args) => args.reduce((r, fn) => r && fn(), true)
```

and you can call it like this:

```
evaluate(() => !isPostingConfig, onClickAway, clearRoleError)
```

---

If you don't want to wrap all expressions with a function, you can add a typeof check:

```
const evaluate = (...args) => args.reduce((r, item) => r && (typeof item === 'function' ? item() : item), true)
```

and call it like this:

```
evaluate(!isPostingConfig, onClickAway, clearRoleError)
```